# Suppress tslint messages when 'ionic serve'

Tags: ionic2, tslint, ionic3

Does anybody have an idea how can I suppress tslint messages in terminal when running 'ionic serve'?
I have imported some external components and there are pretty much unused imports there that's filling up my terminal container quite quickly and prevent me to see other important messages there. There are also other warnings there that are not so important so I just want to suppress that.

Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that changing the rules in configuration file tslint.json can help with that.

```
  {
   ... 
   "rules": {
      "no-duplicate-variable": true,
      "no-unused-variable": [
        false
      ]   },
   ...
   }
```

Or a pattern can be used, like here:
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-variable/